# Unitary matrices rotating two given vectors into each other

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Given the $n+1$-dimensional complex vector space together with its standard hermitian scalar product and its standard basis $(\mathbf{e}_i)^j = \delta_i^j$. Given a vector $v$, is there a general way to obtain a matrix $R \in U(n+1)$ such that
$$
R \mathbf{e}_{n+1} \in \mathbb{C} v
$$
that is, $R$ rotates $\mathbf{e}_{n+1}$ into the ray of $v$? There are many such $R$, but it would suffice to find one (the others a found through $U(n)$ transformations) however it should depend smoothly on the ray.

for $n=1$, this can be done as follows:

A general $\text{SU}_2$ transformation has the form
\begin{align*}
R = \begin{pmatrix}
a^* &&  b\\
-b^* && a
\end{pmatrix} \ ,
\end{align*}
where 
\begin{align}
|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1 \ . \label{eq:abConstraint}
\end{align}
Demanding that $R \mathbf{e}_2 \in \mathbb{C}z$ leads to the following equation, with $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^\times$:
\begin{align*}
(b,a) = \lambda (z^1,z^2) \ .
\end{align*}
To obtain more explicit formulas, restrict first to $z^1 \neq 0$. Then:
\begin{align*}
\frac{z^2}{z^1} = \frac{a}{b} \ .
\end{align*}
from there one derives, using the constraint on $a$ and $b$, $|b| = (1 + |z^2/z^1|^2)^{-1/2}$ and $|a| = |z^2/z^1||b|$. Hence denoting the phases of $a,b$ by $\theta_a,\theta_b$ respectively, 
\begin{align}
\frac{z^2}{z^1} =  \left|\frac{z^2}{z^1}\right| e^{i(\theta_a-\theta_b)} \ . \label{eq:abPhases}
\end{align}
This equation fixes the relative phase of $a,b$. However, the requirement of smoothness of $R$ fixes $\theta_b = 0$ (or a constant). The reason is that the vanishing of $z^2$ is allowed. In this case the phase of $z^2/z^1$ becomes ill-defined. So if this phase appears in $R$, its coefficient should go to zero as well in this case.
This fixes 
\begin{align*}
a_1 = \frac{\frac{z^2}{z^1}}{\sqrt{1 +  \left|\frac{z^2}{z^1}\right|^2}} \ , \quad b_1  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 +  \left|\frac{z^2}{z^1}\right|^2}} \ .
\end{align*}

Comment: It is hopefully not strictly necessary for understanding the problem, that's why i did not put it in the text, but i wanted to comment on the motivation: The tangent space of complex projective space at a point $\mathbb{C}z$ is isomorphic to the vectors orthogonal to $z$. Therefore, constructing such maps gives a frame.

Comment: A unitary matrix is the "same" as an orthonormal basis; i.e. the columns of a unitary matrix form an ONB and vice versa.  Have you considered using Gram-Schmidt?

Comment: Yes; however it doesn't seem to be very useful for computations.